# Find out Probability?

Tags: probability

In a triangular series, probability of the Indian team winning match against Pakistan is 0.7 and that against Australia is 0.4.If the probability of Indian winning both matches is 0.3, what is the probability that India will win minimum one match so that it can enter final?

Comment: $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that India wins against Australia but not against Pakistan is 0.4-0.3=0.1. The probability that they win against Pakistan but not against Australia is 0.7-0.3=0.4. The probability that they win at least one game is the sum of the probabilities that they win only against Australia, only against Pakistan and against both, therefore it equals 0.4+0.1+0.3=0.8.